# How can I pause an Image View update by pressing a button?

Tags: java, android, button, handler, wait

I am a coding an app that receives images over a network continuously and has a handler to post to update the Image View with each new image.  I want to be able to add pause and resume buttons in order to stop the image view from updating with the new images until the resume button is pressed. Here is the code that I have for those buttons so far:

```
 Button.OnClickListener pauseOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 synchronized(imageIn){
     try {
        imageIn.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}

};

Button.OnClickListener resumeOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   synchronized(imageIn){
       imageIn.notify();

   }

}

};
```

When I run the code and press the pause button, it says that the application isn't responding. Any comments or suggestions on what I did wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make a boolean named e.g. "pause" and put the image updater into a while loop with the condition while (!paused). The button Pause will obviously control the boolean.

Comment: how exactly would I do that? Sorry.. I'm still relatively new to Java coding

Comment: Look at the second answer, it follows my idea. Basically, the Pause/Unpause button sets true/false of the Pause boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this kind of code.

```
boolean isPause = false;

while(1=1){
if(!isPause){
    // code for update ur image 
 }
}


onPauseButtonClick(){
isPause=true;
 }
```

Make sure this is just logic you have to check according to your code.